# 4DGenome or another comprehensive database of chromatin interactions

Tags: chromosome, database, data, chromatin

I'm searching for the most comprehensive source of chromatin interactions to support enhancer targets (data such like Hi-C, ChIA-PET, IM-PET, 5C, 4C, 3C, etc.) and my question according that could be split into two following parts:

1. On page http://epigenie.com/epigenetic-tools-and-databases/ I've found out links to two databases, but the reference to 4D Genome doesn't work. **Does anybody know whether this database
   http://4dgenome.int-med.uiowa.edu was moved somewhere else or maybe its only internally available for U Iowa community?** (I'm asking about probably exclusive access, because on Tan's lab page http://www.healthcare.uiowa.edu/labs/tan/software.html only the 4DGenome has the trailing part of the link *int-med.uiowa.edu* (presumably this **int-med** strands for internal/general medicine or maybe in the sense of internal/intranet access), whereas all other services like IM-PET has its link starting with *http://www.healthcare.uiowa.edu/labs/tan/*.
2. **Maybe you know even better database for chromatin interactions covering as much as possible cell lines/tissue types for GRCh38 assembly or any other whose coordinates could be easily converted, e.g. by *liftOver*?** I need data only for human and mouse, but I would be grateful also for solely human data.

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: All the sequencing data can be found in SRA. You just have to use the keyword to get the data. However, these would be raw data. [This](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26868054) seems to be another database on long range chromatin interactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been finally solved with help from prof. Kai Tan.
It occurred that his lab has been moved from University of Iowa to Children's Hopspital of Philadelphia, so has been this service.
Now, the working link is: 
**http://4dgenome.research.chop.edu**